# Installing Canon MF414dw Printer on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing, 16.10

How do I install a Canon MF414dw printer on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10?

I tried to install it, but I was unable to print to it. However, it was in the list of printers, so this makes no sense. What can I do?

Comment: Please help us help you! Tried to install it following what instructions? How are you trying to print to it and what happens when you try?